# implementing a dynamically sized stack using an array,elements printing error

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic, malloc

The structure stack has a pointer 'a' to a dynamically allocated array (used to hold the contents of the stack), an integer 'maxSize' that holds the size of this array (i.e the maximum number of data that can be held in this array) and an integer 'top' which stores the array index of the top element in the stack.

In the initstack function intialize the value of top to -1 and initialize the value of maxSize.
Print the message “Stack is full” in the push function when an attempt is made to push a data into a full stack.
Print the message “Stack is empty” in the pop function and return the value -1000 when an attempt is made to pop data from an empty stack.

In the initstack function intialize the value of top to -1 and initialize the value of maxSize.

Print the message “Stack is full” in the push function when an attempt is made to push a data into a full stack.

Print the message “Stack is empty” in the pop function and return the value -1000 when an attempt is made to pop data from an empty stack.

Note that the statement “The contents of the stack are” is in the main function. In the display function, if the stack is empty, print “ {}”.

Problem with my code:

- It's not taking the required amount of values.
- And secondly i am not able to print the elements.

  ```
   #include<stdio.h>
   #include<stdlib.h>
   struct stack
     {
       int * a;
       int top;
       int maxSize;
     };
  void initstack(struct stack * p, int maxSize);
  void push(struct stack * p, int item);
  void display(struct stack p);
  int pop(struct stack * p);
  void printMenu();

    int main()  
     {
       struct stack p;
       int data,ch, data1, m;
       printf("Enter the maximum size of the stack\n");
       scanf("%d",&m);
       initstack(&p,m);
       do
         {
           printMenu();
           printf("Enter your choice\n");
           scanf("%d",&ch);
           switch(ch)
             {
                case 1:
                printf("Enter the element to be pushed\n");
                scanf("%d",&data);
                push(&p, data);
                break;

                case 2:
                data1 = pop(&p);
                if(data1 != -1000)
                printf("The popped element is %d\n",data1);
                break;

                case 3:
                printf("The contents of the stack are");
                display(p);
                printf("\n");
                break;

                default:
                return 0;
             }
         }
      while(1);
      return 0;
    }

     void printMenu()
       {
        printf("Choice 1 : Push\n");
        printf("Choice 2 : Pop\n");
        printf("Choice 3 : Display\n");
        printf("Any other choice : Exit\n");
       }

      void initstack(struct stack * p, int maxSize) 
       {
         p->top=-1;
         p->maxSize=maxSize;
       }

     void push(struct stack * p, int item) 
       {
         if (p->top == p->maxSize-1) 
           {
            printf("Stack is full\n");
            return;
           }
      p->a = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
      p->top++;
      p->a[p->top] =item;
      p->maxSize--;

     }

      void display(struct stack p) 
       {
         struct stack *p1;
         p1=&p;
         int a[30],n=0,i;
         for (i = p1->top ; i >= 0; i--)
          {
            printf("\n%d", p1->a[i]);

          }

        }

       int pop(struct stack * p) 
        {
          int num;
          if(p->top == -1)
           {
             printf("Stack is empty\n");
             return -1000;
           }
        num = p->a[p->top];
        p->top--;
        return num;
      }
  ```

Comment: Please strip down the code to an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and format it properly (4 spaces per indentation level).

Comment: "It's not taking the required amount of values". That's what it is not doing, so what is it doing instead (e.g. crashing after X values? taking all values but ignoring them?...?). "i am not able to print the elements"..again, that's what it is not doing so what is it doing instead?

Comment: 1)`p->a=(int *)malloc(p->maxSize * sizeof(stack));` should be `p->a=(int *)malloc(maxSize * sizeof(int));`

Comment: @Olaf elements input and popping.

Comment: @Olafwhen i am giving the maxSize 3 it inputs the elements correctly but if i give 4 after inputting 3 values it starts giving me message stack full.

Comment: 2)at `push` : `p->a = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));` and `p->maxSize--;` are wrong.

Comment: @Olaf now the 2nd problem is i am confused printing the stack elements reversely that means if the input is 1,2,3 than i should print them like 1,2,3 not 3,2,1

Comment: 3) at display : `for(i=n;i<=0;i--){`, `i=n` should be `i=n-1`

Comment: Do you actually have a specific question? Correct the formating. I will _not_ read this code unitl properly formatted at least! The current formatiing doe not show much effort on your side to get that code running.

Comment: @DeepakKumar: Why should I? Apparently you are not even interested to properly format your own code to help others analyse it. In case you have no idea about proper formating: just google. It need not be perfect, but al least properly indented, so one can see the structure. As far as I see from the code now, it is sprinkled with bugs and needs a major overhaul. I suppose that is because of not understood basic concepts. No offense! It's just that this would require a tutor for you or at least a site you can discuss your code.

Answer (score 3):

Quite some things go wrong in this code.

First off, Olafs remark to properly format the code might appear harsh but it is justified. Depending on the editor you use, all it takes is 2 keystrokes. (e.g. CTRL-k-f in Visual Studio). To get the code into the question on SO, the secret is (again in VS): CTRL-a (mark all) TAB CTRL-C and you have the initial 4 indents required for source code to show as source code on this site.

Second, no one these days would initialize top with -1. There is no benefit to it, really. Usually, you would initialize with 0. Then, the stack is empty if `p->top == 0`. And the stack is full, if `p->maxSize == p->top`. And the topmost value on the stack (if not empty) is `p->a[p->top - 1]`.

Next, your `initstack()` function is the one who is supposed to `p->a = malloc(maxSize * sizeof(int));`. Unless there is a special requirement to create a lazy stack or whatnot.

Your display functions stack parameter is passed by value (forgotten '*').

```
void display(struct stack *p) {
    if (NULL != p)
    {
        if (NULL != p->a)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < p->top; i++)
            {
                printf("%d\n", p->a[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, in general there is not sufficient parameter checking going on. If someone passes a pointer to a function the function is responsible to not access it if it is NULL. (Defensive programming). In general a function is responsible not to corrupt memory or perform illegal access.

Next, whenever you have an init function you should also create a cleanup function. Here the pair of both. The signature of `initstack()` is somewhat lacking, btw. Whenever there is something that can fail (here: `malloc()`), the function can fail and it thus should have a status return value so the caller can react to the fact that the stack is not really initialized as desired in case of out of memory (or heap fragmentation or whatever else might lead malloc to fail).

```
void initstack(struct stack * p, int maxSize) {
    p->top = 0;
    p->maxSize = maxSize;
    p->a = malloc(maxSize * sizeof(int));
}

void uninitstack(struct stack* p) {
    free(p->a);
    p->a = NULL;
    p->maxSize = 0;
    p->top = 0;
}
```

Here the somewhat fixed push function with the basic error checking code:

```
void push(struct stack * p, int item) {
    if (p == NULL){
        printf("Invalid argument. p == NULL.\n");
    }
    if (p->a == NULL) {
        printf("Stack not initialized.\n");
            return;
    }
    if (p->top == p->maxSize) {
        printf("Stack is full\n");
        return;
    }
    if (p->top < p->maxSize) {
        p->a[p->top] = item;
        p->top++;
    }
}
```

Last not least the respective pop function:

```
int pop(struct stack * p) {
    if (NULL != p)
    {
        if (NULL != p->a) {
            if (p->top == 0) {
                printf("{}\n");
                return -1000;
            }
            else {
                p->top--;
                return p->a[p->top];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `push()` routine, you have:

```
 p->a = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

But you've already allocated space for `p->a` in your `initstack()` routine.
This code is wiping out whatever was previously stored in the stack.

Comment: @jimok now what should i do for printing.

Answer (score 0):

```
//This program works perfectly

   #include<stdio.h>
     #include<stdlib.h>
     struct stack
       {
         int * a;
         int top;
         int maxSize;
       };
    void initstack(struct stack * p, int maxSize);
    void push(struct stack * p, int item);
    void display(struct stack p);
    int pop(struct stack * p);
    void printMenu();

      int main()  
       {
         struct stack p;
         int data,ch, data1, m;
         printf("Enter the maximum size of the stack\n");
         scanf("%d",&m);
         initstack(&p,m);
         do
           {
             printMenu();
             printf("Enter your choice\n");
             scanf("%d",&ch);
             switch(ch)
               {
                  case 1:
                  printf("Enter the element to be pushed\n");
                  scanf("%d",&data);
                  push(&p, data);
                  break;

                  case 2:
                  data1 = pop(&p);
                  if(data1 != -1000)
                  printf("The popped element is %d\n",data1);
                  break;

                  case 3:
                  printf("The contents of the stack are");
                  display(p);
                  printf("\n");
                  break;

                  default:
                  return 0;
               }
           }
        while(1);
        return 0;
      }

       void printMenu()
         {
          printf("Choice 1 : Push\n");
          printf("Choice 2 : Pop\n");
          printf("Choice 3 : Display\n");
          printf("Any other choice : Exit\n");
         }

        void initstack(struct stack * p, int maxSize) 
         {
      p->maxSize=maxSize;
      p->a=(int*)malloc(maxSize*sizeof(int));
      p->top=-1;
         }

       void push(struct stack * p, int item) 
         {
      if (p->top == p->maxSize - 1) {
          printf("Stack is full\n");
          return ;
       }
       p->top++;
       p->a[p->top] = item;
         }

        void display(struct stack p) 
         {
      int i,jp=0;
       for (i =0; i<=p.top; i++)
       {
          // if(p.top!=0)
           jp++;
          printf(" %d", p.a[i]);
       }
       if(jp==0)
       printf(" {}");
          }

    int pop(struct stack * p) 
    {
       int num;
       if (p->top == -1) {
          printf("Stack is empty\n");
          return -1000;
       }
       num = p->a[p->top];
       p->top--;
       return num;
        }
```